# retrieve Soundcloud user resource from Soundcloud track resource

Tags: python, search, soundcloud

I am trying to 'trace back' from a given Soundcloud track resource object to the Soundcloud user resource object that created it. Given my understanding of the Soundcloud API this is what I have done.

1st: Retrieve a specific track

```
track = client.get('/tracks', title="White Lies (feat. Jenni Potts)",
                              limit=1)
```

This should return a collection of one track (by Odesza).

2nd: Gather info about tracks user from track resource

```
white_lies_perma = track[0].user["permalink"]
white_lies_uID = track[0].user["id"]
```

3rd: Get the user (hopefully) using the above filters

```
users = client.get('/users',
                id=white_lies_uID,
                permalink=white_lies_perma)
```

This should return 1 user, however the length of the resource collection is 50 (the API default). This is strange.

Printing the values:

```
for user in users:
    print(user.id)
```

79582

2684450

3765692

9918957

12470953

etc...

This should just be a collection of length 1, containing a resource with id 18604897.

Furthermore, this code should reasonably return "Oklahoma City" twenty times over. However when run it gives me "Cape St Francis", "Augusta", "London U.K".

```
client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='xxxxx')
okcUsers = client.get('/users',city="Oklahoma City",limit=20)
for okcUser in okcUsers:
    print okcUser.city
```

Is something wrong with Soundcloud's API?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you implemented those filters in your 3rd call, but I think you should get the information you needed if you do

`users = client.get('/users/%d' % white_lies_uID)`

Since you do not need to do a search but just call the correct /users/ endpoint. To see which endpoints are available for a specific user go to https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users and scroll down to below the list of fields a user contains. There you see a list of endpoints that can be called once you have a user id.